# Ember: setting element id of nested component

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js

I have an Ember.Component that I use to wrap some other content.  Here are my templates.

```
# index.hbs:
   {{render "wrapped"}}

# wrapped.hbs:
   {{#outside-thing}}
     <p>I go inside</p>
   {{/outside-thing}}

# components/outside-thing.hbs:
   <p>I'm on top</p>
   {{yield}}
   <p>I'm on bottom</p>
```

Since `outside-thing` is a component, it's going to get its own div.  That's good.  The problem is, I want to be able to set the `id` of that div from the `index.hbs` template.  E.g., something like:

```
# index.hbs:
   {{render "wrapped" outerId='wrapper-div-id'}}

# wrapped.hbs:
   {{#outside-thing id=outerId}}
     <p>I go inside</p>
   {{/outside-thing}}

# components/outside-thing.hbs:
   <p>I'm on top</p>
   {{yield}}
   <p>I'm on bottom</p>
```

Except the above doesn't work.  So, is this possible?  Note that I don't care if I have to use a different helper than `render` (e.g. `view` is fine).

Here's a JSBin to play with: http://jsbin.com/ucanam/3182/edit

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Actually, I do not think you are able to pass in properties to the render handlebars helper. It seems a bit of a strange requirement, though...

Comment: In case you're curious, my actual use case is this: I'm making a Bootstrap 3 modal, and I wanted outside-thing.hbs to be all of the necessary wrapping divs, then it would yield to wrapped.hbs to fill in the body of the modal.  But to trigger the modal from an HTML element, you need to associate the id of that outermost div with the data-target of said element.  So I want to be able to set it in the index template.